# How can I prevent a Virtual Machine from copy on the host?

Tags: security, encryption, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I've been distributing a few virtual machines as 'beta' version of an project, but I don't have a specific security system on it so far. So, I'm looking for a way to only enable access to the virtual machine with my approval.

I learned that VMware has an (apparently nice) encrypt system, but every time the machine is run the user has to insert the key, so it doesn't work for me (because I would have to tell the users the key, otherwise I would have to remotely access every time they started the machine and type the key). I can set an expiration date for the machine, but the machine still could be distributed (without my approval) within the term I set.

I need some kind of key that I insert while accessing through TeamViewer (only the first time the machine run) and that stays saved in the host machine (like 'remember password'), but that doesn't show up to the user, so if he/she try to compact/copy the virtual machine and run in another PC, he/she will need the key.

I also learned that VMware ACE did a good job at securing and preventing unauthorized copies, but it is been discontinuated since 2011, and the last VMware Workstation compatible with it is 7, so I think it would be unhandy. If there was a more updated similar product, it believe it could solve my problem.

Comment: **How can I prevent a Virtual Machine from copy on the host?** - Terms of Use, End User License Agreement, etc., etc.

Comment: I understand and agree that terms of use and license agreement are paramount, but I'm looking after a way to enforce protection, like VMware ACE. Any suggestions that have a similar result would be welcome.